# Is there a conventional way to ship vendor-specific C package along with Swift codebase?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I want to use an existing complexly built library written in C from my Swift client code.

Let us use OpenSSL as the example. Most of the existing solutions use either a binding to a system-wide library [[IBM]](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/OpenSSL) or a transformed source tree in a way understood by Swift PM [[PerfectlySoft]](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-COpenSSL-Linuxhttps://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-COpenSSL-Linux).

I do not want to use the system-provided package, because of the compatibility uncertainty: I want to use the exact same version on the build server, and on the deployment target. It also complicates the installation process. I as well do not want to use transformed source tree, because this approach is fragile, and, if I'm not mistaken, there is no readily available tool to perform it automatically.

What I tried is checking into my repo a pristine release of OpenSSL, and providing it with a custom modulemap and an umbrella header. The main issue I'm facing is that Swift PM is unable to see it as a module out of the box:

```
$ swift test
.../Tests.swift:5:8: error: no such module 'OpenSSL'
```

However, Xcode with the correct `-I` and `-L` custom flags does build it.

I am alright with keeping that version OpenSSL in my repo, even pre-configured, and I am even alright with an additional build-step, such as `make`, before `swift test`. Even though it lowers the developer ergonomics, it is not too much worse as installing a system-wide lib. What I am not alright with is using Xcode as the only build tool.

Ideally, I want to make Swift PM to pass appropriate `-I`, `-L`, `-l` to the compiler. Any examples or hints would be appreciated.